# Xamarin custom activity indicator

Tags: xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

Im trying to use a custom Activity indicator for xamarin forms.
I supose this shouldnt be that hard to do or find but for w/e reason I dont find any way to add a gif and use it as an activity indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use gifs in Xamarin as is so you'd have to use a WebView to achieve this. See this repo for full example: https://github.com/LeslieCorrea/Xamarin-Forms-Custom-Activity-Indicator

Simpler still, just realized FFImageLoading supports gifs:
https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

But my 2 cents - recommend using Lottie animations. There are plenty [available online](https://www.lottiefiles.com) and you can even customize them (at a basic level, e.g. changing colors) before downloading. [Adding to your project](https://xamgirl.com/lottie-animations-step-by-step-in-xamarin-forms/) is simple and the animations are silky smooth.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that Lottie is the best option, but it is also worth researching about Xamanimation. He is very easy to work with and more customizable than Lottie, although I think Lottie is the best option in this case.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamanimation/

Comment: This is an opinion, not a solution.